# Wrap a method in commands using Annotation Processing

Tags: java, android, reflection, kotlin, annotations

I have a bunch of tasks that need to be performed before and after a method call.

My approach is to use annotation processing, and a custom annotation to do this.

```
@BeforeSomething(task = 'something')
@AfterSomething(task = 'something else')
fun something(blah: Something) {
  Log.d("Something", "Something $blah")
}
```

So that the end output from just running this method could be like:

```
Before task, options 'something'
Something blahblahblah
After task, options 'somethign else'
```

Whats the best way to do this?  I've looked into AspectJ but thats not working with Kotlin.  I've also looked into Lombok, but I can't use that library.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the tasks via a higher order function - a wrapper function:

```
inline fun <T> wrapFunction(before: Task? = null, after: Task? = null, body: () -> T): T =
    try {
        before?.run()
        body()
    } finally {
        after?.run()
    }

fun something(blah: String)  = wrapFunction(before = BeforeTask, after = AfterTask)  {
    println("Something")
}
```

This requires no extra tools and is refactoring safe.
If you not provide a `before` or `after` parameter the Kotlin compiler will not even generate the `null`-check, due to dead code elimination (abstractions without costs).